# highlight the linearlayout background in android

Tags: android, android-listview, sharedpreferences, background-color, pressed

I have to develop one android application. 
Here is the scenario:There are many images in a linearlayout. When selected, the layout should be displayed with another background. This works well now.

Now, I would like that when I open a new activity and come back tho this one, the last selected layout should still be the highlighted one (with the second background).

How can this be done ???

Now i have used below code for highlighting the image when pressed:

```
LinearLayout ar = new LinearLayout(this);
            ar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            ar.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            ar.setLayoutParams(artiLayoutParams);
            ar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
            ar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_selector));
ar.setId(position);
            position++;
         ar.setOnClickListener(mArticleClick);
```

**EDIT:**

```
private OnClickListener mArticleClick = new OnClickListener()
    {

       @Override
      public void onClick ( View v )
         {
        int object = v.getId();
         v.setSelected(true);

        String articletitle = Appscontent.Sub_arraylist.get(object).toString();
            Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubCate.class);
        in.putExtra("Title", articletitle);
    startActivity(in);
    }
    };
```

Here i have to clicked one item means it is go to next activity.afterthat i have clicked back button means the selected item is stay on highlighted with another background.afterthat i have selected another item means its go to next activity.now i have to click back button means these item only highlight with background....but the pervious item also highlighted....

I wish to need the o/p like :

The last selected item only highlighted after click the back button...please help me...how can i do ..

**EDIT:**

I have declared int prevPosition = -1; globally...

Afterthat i have save the value here:

```
    ar = new LinearLayout(this);
                ar.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
              ar.setPadding(3, 3, 3, 3);
            ar.setLayoutParams(artiLayoutParams);
            ar.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            ar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
            ar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_selector));
            ar.setId(position);
            position++;
            ar.setOnClickListener(mArticleClick);
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putLong("POSITION", prevPosition);
            editor.commit();
```

In Onclick method:

```
      private OnClickListener mArticleClick = new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick ( View v )
            {

                int object = v.getId();

 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
          editor.putLong("POSITION", -1);
        editor.commit();
```

But my background color is not staying here after press the back button...

Answer (score 0):

This is "easy". In order to be able to know which image should be highlighted, you need to store this information somewere. A good practice is a database, but if you have only this info to store, you can create something like a shared preferance or some other types of global variables. Then, when you will re-open the activity with your listview (or come back to it), you should tell to your listview which item should be highlighted and highlight this item.

Comment: What you can't understand? Have you tryed something?

Comment: please read my updated question and give me solution for these.here i have used sharedpreferences.but i didn't get correct solution..whats wrong in my code.pls give me some idea ???